# Rails 3.0 / JQuery - Swapping partials on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have two partials _choose.html.erb and _details.html.erb.

I render choose like so:

```
<div id="choose" class="box" style="padding:10px;" >
        <%= render :partial => "choose" %> 
</div>
```

In the controller I call the choose method.

```
def choose  
    respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
end
```

And in choose.js.erb I call the following:

```
$("#choose").replaceWith(<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "details"))%>);
```

But nothing happens.  The details partial is in the correct place and if I render it in the page, like so   <%= render :partial => "details" %>, up it pops no problem.  But I am unable to swap it using the above ajax method.

If I do:

```
$("#choose").replaceWith("a yaddy yaddy");
```

"a yaddy yaddy" is rendered in the choose div.

Am I missing something here?

I have been reading around, including SO, but to no avail.

#### Update

The response is either a `200` or a `304`. And using firebug, I can see that the response contains the partial contents but this is not rendered in the browser, which is strange, but I'd imagine I have committed some sneaky grievance I'm unaware of....

#### Update

in choose.js.erb:

If I call `"$("#choose").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "choose", :object => @pages))%>")"` the choose partial is updated with the pages instance variable.

Thanks, y'all.

Comment: You can try to debug it in the browser using Firebug (Firefox plugin) or Safari/Chrome/IE equivalents. That way you can see exactly what is sent to the browser.

Comment: I've done that, the first request is a 200, and then the following ones, I try, are 304 (unmodified).  However, the partial contents appears in the response but is not rendered in the browser.

Comment: Do you have jQuery integrated in Rails? Or just a standard jQuery and the standard Rails Prototype library? In other words: do you have the 'jquery-rails' gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: I don't have 'jquery-rails' gem installed but I have Jquery in my javascripts directory and I have the rails.js (UJS) in the javascripts also.  I also have config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails application) in my application config. Do I need to include the gem also?

Comment: Also, there are no other javascripts in the javascripts directory.

Comment: Honestly, ditch RJS. It's been extracted to a separate gem for 3.1, and it combines concerns.

Comment: Hey @coreyward, thanks for the comment.  However, I did not think I was using RJS here.  I thought I was using JQuery with html.erb templates?  I'm easy with how I accomplish this, but a little uncertain of the approach now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you make sure that both of your partials have a `id = "choose"` div in them?  If not, your `replaceWith` is dropping them.  Could you possible want `.html("")`?

Comment: Neither partial has a choose div. The _choose.html.erb is rendered in the choose div, and I try to replace this partial with the detials partial.  I can use .append() either but with no luck.

Comment: Boooooooooooooooooooooooom!  It worked.  I thought I tried it earlier but obviously I screwed it up.  Cheers man.  One quick Q, this is not RJS?  Correct?  BTW .html("") worked not the choose div....

Comment: RJS is an older approach where you actually used rails helpers to insert javascript.  This is just a JS response.  You're actually using jQuery when you're talking about `.append` `.html` and `.replaceWith`.  The `replaceWith` is actually overwriting the entire div rather than just inserting into it. `.html` inserts your partial inside it, and keeps it but keeps the `choose` div around

Comment: That's what I thought.  The other guy said I should stop using RJS, which, I ain't.  Anyhow, thanks for your help.